# $pull function doesn't work Mongoose. Any ideas

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I was trying to do a system but i realized that Mongoose's $pull function out of a model just doesn't work. Any help?

Example

```
await Model.findOneAndUpdate({
     _id: id
},
{
    $pull:{
          Array:{
                thing:thing
          }
    }
})
```

(Should i maybe update mongoose)

Comment: Can you post your `Model` declaration and full function code?

Comment: const Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            userId: String,
            following:[],
            posts:[],
            liked:[],
            tokens: Number,
            description: String,
            id: Number,
            joined: Date
        }
    )

Comment: and inside the posts it pushes
    await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                userId:i.user.id,
            },
            {
                $push:{
                    posts:{
                        title:title,
                        image:image,
                        description:description,
                        tag:tag,
                        likes:0,
                        dislikes:0,
                        id: id,
                        author:i.user.id
                    }
                },
            }
        )

Comment: and i want it to pull the posts if it was liked 

    await userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        userId:user.id
    },
    {
        $pull:{
              liked:{
                    title:title,
                    image:image,
                    description:description,
                    tag:tag,
                    likes:likes,
                    dislikes:dislikes,
                    id:id,
                    author:author
              }
        }
    }
    )

Comment: also it pushes inside the liked not posts

Comment: Hey @LucaPizzini

Comment: You can try using the syntax from this example: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents